# multiple same cast on object

Tags: c#, .net

I was checking article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful

```
while(e.MoveNext())
  {
    int m; // INSIDE
    m = (int)(int)e.Current;
    funcs.Add(()=>m);
  }
```

I searched about it, but didn't find **why in `m = (int)(int)e.Current;` its cast twice?** I did check but both had same result and

```
((int)(int)e.Current).GetType() = Int32
((int)e.Current).GetType() = Int32
(e.Current).GetType() = Int32
```

Comment: You should ask to [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

Comment: do we have tag named eric?

Comment: @brykneval Nope, I don't how to do it and I don't even know if this is possible http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40879/whats-the-best-way-to-invite-a-user-to-answer-a-question-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @HansPassant is it really a typo? as suggested on one answer, Explanation is in page 7 of Q/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation is in page 7 of Q/A

> Pavel Minaev [MSFT] 15 Nov 2009 11:15 PM
>
> @Brad: according to the
> definition of foreach in the language spec, there are two types
> involved: element type (which is normally the type of Current property
> of the enumerator), and iteration variable type (which is the type you
> explicitly specify in foreach, or same as element type if you use
> "var"). The associated line of the expansion of foreach is this:
>
> ```
>    v = (V)(T)e.Current;
> ```
>
> So far as I can see, the (T) cast will almost always be a no-op,
> because it will correspond to type of Current. Seemingly the only case
> where this isn't so is when you're iterating over an array (the spec
> requires the use of IEnumerable over IEnumerable in that case, and
> element type is derived not from Current, but from array type).
>
> I wonder why it wasn't simply redefined to use IEnumerable for
> arrays as well (which would remove the need to special-case that, as
> well as the cast) - so far as I can see, the change wouldn't be
> observable to the user...

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason. Period.

Comment: You're the only person on the world who says that it's a bad article.

Comment: The article is not bad, it's a typo.

Comment: I guess I mean the double cast is bad, not the whole article, sorry.

Comment: @PetarIvanov is it really a typo? as suggested on one answer, Explanation is in page 7 of Q/A

Answer (score 0):

It is really just a typo (yes, this happens even to Eric).

What i already seen in code is a double cast with two types, because otherwise it would fail. Like this example:

```
double? nullableDouble = 3;
int myInteger = (int)(double)nullableDouble;
```